# Constraint optimization in TensorFlow (or GPFlow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, gpflow

An example is the following: The goal is to optimize a function `f(x1,..,xN)` subject to the constraint `x1 + .. + xN = 1` with `0 < x_i <= 1`. How do I do this with tensorflow in general (with arbitrary constraints)?

I have seen the [ScipyOptimizerInterface](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ScipyOptimizerInterface) which allows to do this.

In this special case, a different approach is to use the `nnsoftmax` transform to write `x_i = exp(y_i)/sum_i(exp(y_i))`, `i=1,..,N`. `y1,..,yN` are unconstrained now and can be optimized with SGD, i.e. with TensorFlow without any constraints. In GPFlow, this would be equivalent to a transform associated to the variables `{y1,..,yN}`.

Is there any other approach?

Comment: This feels broad. In general, with arbitrary constraints, you will need some NLP-solver (which are mostly Interior-point based; quite complex software) like Ipopt (where the final question then is: how transfer tf's differentiation capabilities to ipopt's core). There is much tf-free software doing autodiff (mathematical-programming; but mostly based on full-batch opt). The simple example allows *projection on the probability-simplex* and as this projection is cheap (linear-time if done right) one approach is: projected (stochastic) gradient (own optimizer not hard to implement)